# Convert dictionary values to be inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I´m trying to convert the values inside a dictionary to be in a list (for future upload in mySQL).

So currently I have the dictionary like below:

```
old_dict = {'key1':'value1','key2':value2,'key3':'value3'}
```

And I´m looking for something like:

```
new_dict = {'key1':['value1'],'key2':[value2],'key3':['value3']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_dict = {k: [v] for k, v in old_dict.items()}
```